# No Settings -> Window Manager in XFCE4

Tags: configuration, xfce, window-manager, settings

I am under Ubuntu 20.04, using XFCE4.
When I click *Menu (Upper left cross)* -> *Settings* in the *Applications Menu* (added to the panel via this)

[image]

I expected to have *Window Manager* available (PS: I needed that to setup keyboard shortcuts for [window tiling](https://www.reddit.com/r/archlinux/comments/95jv6x/tiling_windows_in_xfce/), which were not set by default).

But I don't have that menu entry, this is what I have.

[image]

I can go to the *Window Manager* via CLI with `xfwm4-settings` ([source](https://www.reddit.com/r/xfce/comments/9h43aq/cant_access_window_manager_settings/), and [related old post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/97871/open-xfce-window-manager-settings-from-command-line)).

By typing `xfce4-`+<kbd>Tab</kbd> (for tab completion), and likewise for `xfwm4-`, I realized there are quite a few other settings that do not show under *Menu (Upper left cross)* -> *Settings*.
Of all tab completion alternatives (shown below), I checked executing some of them at the CLI, and then if they show in the menus. None of them were present (and perhaps none of the others as well!).
These are marked with an asterisk.

```
xfce4-about
xfce4-accessibility-settings
*xfce4-appearance-settings
xfce4-appfinder
xfce4-color-settings
xfce4-display-settings
xfce4-find-cursor
*xfce4-keyboard-settings
xfce4-mime-settings
*xfce4-mouse-settings
xfce4-notifyd-config
xfce4-panel
xfce4-popup-applicationsmenu
xfce4-popup-directorymenu
xfce4-popup-windowmenu
xfce4-session
xfce4-session-logout
xfce4-settings-editor
xfce4-settings-manager
xfce4-session-settings
xfwm4
*xfwm4-settings 
*xfwm4-tweaks-settings
*xfwm4-workspace-settings
```

The CLI settings available above seem a completely disjoint set compared to the menu entries.

So:

1. Why are these menu entries not present? (I guess they should be automatically included)
2. How can I have them shown?

Comment: I'm using XFCE Whisker Menu applet and I see everything: https://i.imgur.com/UaNgF58.png No idea what's wrong with your setup.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov - See edited OP and answer.

Answer (score 0):

As per comment by @Artem S. Tashkinov,
the XFCE *Whisker Menu* applet is an alternative menu that can be installed with `sudo apt install xfce4-whiskermenu-plugin`, and added to the panel.
It then gives the menu in the left figure.

[image]   ..........   [image]

It contains essentially the same items as the *Applications Menu*, but it shows a small icon (circled in red) that leads to the menu in the right figure, with access to the missing settings.

Besides this providing a solution to the problem,
I still wonder:

1. What tells apart these last settings from the previous.
2. If these settings could also be added to *Applications Menu* (perhaps via an extra icon/submenu).